# Arbor graph Uncaught TypeError: undefined is not a function renderer.js:6 Renderer

Tags: jquery, arbor.js

My project produces an error on rendering and wont produce the graph. The current scripts have been loaded but the renderer is the problem. Here is my code:

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html lang="en">
<head>
<meta charset="utf-8">
<meta http-equiv="X-UA-Compatible" content="IE=edge">
<meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1">
<meta name="description" content="">
<meta name="author" content="">

<title>International Marketing Group</title>

<!-- Bootstrap Core CSS -->
<link href="<?php echo base_url();?>assets/css/bootstrap.min.css" rel="stylesheet">

<!-- Custom CSS -->
<link href="<?php echo base_url();?>assets/css/img.css" rel="stylesheet">

<!-- Custom Fonts -->
<link href="<?php echo base_url();?>assets/font-awesome-4.1.0/css/font-awesome.min.css" rel="stylesheet" type="text/css">

<!-- HTML5 Shim and Respond.js IE8 support of HTML5 elements and media queries -->
<!-- WARNING: Respond.js doesn't work if you view the page via file:// -->
<!--[if lt IE 9]>
    <script src="https://oss.maxcdn.com/libs/html5shiv/3.7.0/html5shiv.js"></script>
    <script src="https://oss.maxcdn.com/libs/respond.js/1.4.2/respond.min.js"></script>
<![endif]-->
</head>

<body>
<!-- Navigation -->
<nav class="navbar navbar-inverse navbar-fixed-top" role="navigation">
    <div class="container">
        <!-- Brand and toggle get grouped for better mobile display -->
        <div class="navbar-header">
            <button type="button" class="navbar-toggle" data-toggle="collapse" data-target="#bs-example-navbar-collapse-1">
                <span class="sr-only">Toggle navigation</span>
                <span class="icon-bar"></span>
                <span class="icon-bar"></span>
                <span class="icon-bar"></span>
            </button>

            <a class="navbar-brand" href="UserHome.php"><img style="max-width:100px; margin-top: -7px;" src="<?php echo base_url();?>assets/images/logo_2.png" width="100px" height="30px" /></a>
        </div>
        <!-- Collect the nav links, forms, and other content for toggling -->
        <div class="collapse navbar-collapse" id="bs-example-navbar-collapse-1">
            <ul class="nav navbar-nav navbar-left">
                <li >
                    <a href="<?php echo base_url();?>index.php/img_controller_user/UserHome" class="glyphicon glyphicon-home" > Home</a>
                </li>
                <li >
                    <a href="<?php echo base_url();?>index.php/img_controller_user/UserAbout" class="glyphicon glyphicon-globe"> About</a>
                </li>
                <li>
                    <a href="<?php echo base_url();?>index.php/img_controller_user/Userservices" class= "glyphicon glyphicon-briefcase" > Services</a>
                </li>
                <li >
                    <a href="<?php echo base_url();?>index.php/img_controller_user/UserContact" class="glyphicon glyphicon-phone"> Contact</a>
                </li>
                  <li class="dropdown">
                        <a href="#" class="dropdown-toggle" data-toggle="dropdown">Options <b class="caret"></b></a>
                        <ul class="dropdown-menu">
                            <li>
                                <a href="<?php echo base_url();?>index.php/img_controller_user/userprofile"><i class="glyphicon glyphicon-edit "></i>
                                     My Profile
                                 </a>
                            </li>
                            <li>
                                <a href="<?php echo base_url();?>index.php/img_controller_network/user_network"><i class="glyphicon glyphicon-edit "></i>
                                     My Network
                                </a>
                            </li>
                            <li>
                                <a href="<?php echo base_url();?>index.php/img_controller_verification/user_logout" ><i class="glyphicon glyphicon-off"></i>
                                     Logout
                                </a>
                            </li>

                        </ul>
                    </li>
            </ul>
        </div>
        <!-- /.navbar-collapse -->

    </div>
    <!-- /.container -->
</nav>

<!-- Page Content -->
<div class="container">

    <!-- Page Heading/Breadcrumbs -->
    <div class="row">
        <div class="col-lg-12">
            <h1 class="page-header"> My Network
                <small>International Marketing Group</small>
            </h1>
            <ol class="breadcrumb">
                <li><a href="UserHome.php">Home</a>
                </li>
                <li class="active">title</li>
            </ol>
        </div>
    </div>

    <!-- /.row -->

    <!-- Intro Content -->

    Uplink
     <table class="table table-hover table-bordered">
                <tr>

                    <td><strong>Recruiter</strong></td>
                    <td><strong>Marketing Director </strong></td>
                    <td><strong>Custodian</strong></td>
                    <td><strong>Referror</strong></td>
                    <td><strong>Trainor</strong></td>
                </tr>
                <?php if(is_array($link) && count($link) ) {
                    foreach($link as $loop){
                ?>
                <tr>
                    <td><?php echo "Name:".$loop->hierarchial_recruiter."<br>";echo "Agent Code:".$loop->hierarchial_recruiter_code;    ?></td>
                    <td><?php echo "Name:".$loop->hierarchial_marketing_director."<br>"; echo "Agent Code:".$loop->hierarchial_marketing_director_code;?></td>
                    <td><?php echo "Name:".$loop->hierarchial_custodian."<br>"; echo "Agent Code:".$loop->hierarchial_custodian_code;?></td>
                    <td><?php echo "Name:".$loop->hierarchial_referror."<br>"; echo "Agent Code:".$loop->hierarchial_referror_code;?></td>          
                    <td><?php echo "Name:".$loop->hierarchial_trainor."<br>"; echo "Agent Code:".$loop->hierarchial_trainor_code;?></td>        
                </tr>
                <?php } 
                }?>
                </table>
    <div class="panel panel-default">
         <div class="panel-heading">Promotion System</div>
     <div class="panel-body">       
   <!--   IMPORTANT LINES     --> 
        <h2>Position:
           <!--  Position call position.js -->
            <label ><?php echo $position[0]->position;?></label>
        </h2>
        Agent Code:<label ><?php echo $position[0]->agent_code;?></label><br>
        Join Date:<label ><?php echo $position[0]->receipt_no;?></label><br>
        Total Member <label ><?php echo $total_downlink;?></label><br>  

  <!--   IMPORTANT LINES     --> 
        <canvas id="viewport" width="800" height="600"></canvas>
  <!--   IMPORTANT LINES     --> 

     </div>
    </div>
    Team Members

    <ul class="nav nav-tabs" role="tablist" id="myTab">
      <li class="active"><a href="#marketing" role="tab" data-toggle="tab">Assistant Marketing Directors</a></li>
      <li><a href="#fieldleader" role="tab" data-toggle="tab">Field Leader</a></li>
      <li><a href="#recruiter" role="tab" data-toggle="tab">Recruits</a></li>
      <li><a href="#trainor" role="tab" data-toggle="tab">Trainees</a></li>
    </ul>
    <div class="tab-content">
      <div class="tab-pane active" id="marketing"> 
         <table class="table table-hover table-bordered">
                <tr>
                    <td class="text-center">
                    <strong></strong></td>
                    <td><strong>Name</strong></td>
                    <td><strong>Agent Code</strong></td>
                    <td><strong>Position</strong></td>
                </tr>
                <?php if(is_array($amd) && count($amd) ) {
                    foreach($amd as $loop){
                ?>
                <tr>
                    <td></td>
                    <td><?php echo $loop->first_name." ".$loop->middle_name." ".$loop->last_name;?></td>
                    <td><?php echo $loop->agent_code;?></td>
                    <td><?php echo $loop->position;?></td>
                </tr>
                <?php } 
                } else
                {
                    echo "<tr><td colspan='4'>No information available</td></tr>";
                }?>
         </table>
     </div>
      <div class="tab-pane" id="recruiter">
         <table class="table table-hover table-bordered">
                <tr>
                    <td class="text-center">
                    <strong></strong></td>
                    <td><strong>Agent Code</strong></td>
                    <td><strong>Name</strong></td>
                    <td><strong>Position</strong></td>
                    <td><strong>Join Date</strong></td>

                </tr>
                <?php if(is_array($recruiter) && count($recruiter) ) {
                    foreach($recruiter as $loop){
                ?>
                <tr>
                    <td></td>
                    <td><?php echo $loop->agent_code;?></td>
                    <td><?php echo $loop->first_name." ".$loop->middle_name." ".$loop->last_name;?></td>
                    <td><?php echo $loop->position;?></td>
                    <td><?php echo $loop->receipt_no;?></td>

                </tr>
                <?php } 
                } else
                {
                    echo "<tr><td colspan='3'>No information available</td></tr>";
                }?>
         </table>
      </div>

      <div class="tab-pane" id="fieldleader">
         <table class="table table-hover table-bordered">
                <tr>
                    <td class="text-center">
                    <strong></strong></td>
                    <td><strong>Name</strong></td>
                    <td><strong>Agent Code</strong></td>
                    <td><strong>Position</strong></td>
                </tr>
                <?php if(is_array($fieldleader) && count($fieldleader)) {
                    foreach($fieldleader as $loop){
                ?>
                <tr>
                    <td></td>
                    <td><?php echo $loop->first_name." ".$loop->middle_name." ".$loop->last_name;?></td>
                    <td><?php echo $loop->agent_code;?></td>
                    <td><?php echo $loop->position;?></td>
                </tr>
                <?php } 
                } else
                {
                    echo "<tr><td colspan='4'>No information available</td></tr>";
                }?>
         </table>
      </div>
       <div class="tab-pane" id="trainor">
         <table class="table table-hover table-bordered">
                <tr>
                    <td class="text-center">
                    <strong></strong></td>
                    <td><strong>Agent Code</strong></td>
                    <td><strong>Name</strong></td>
                    <td><strong>Position</strong></td>

                </tr>
                <?php if(is_array($trainor) && count($trainor) ) {
                    foreach($trainor as $loop){
                ?>
                <tr>
                    <td> <a href="<?php echo base_url();?>index.php/img_controller_network/user_promote_ta/<?php echo $loop->agent_code;?>"><input type="button"  class="btn btn-warning"  value="promote"></a></td>
                    <td><?php echo $loop->agent_code;?></td>
                    <td><?php echo $loop->first_name." ".$loop->middle_name." ".$loop->last_name;?></td>
                    <td><?php echo $loop->position;?></td>
                </tr>
                <?php } 
                } else
                {
                    echo "<tr><td colspan='4'>No information available</td></tr>";
                }?>
         </table>
       </div>
    </div>


 <!-- /.row -->
    <hr>

    <!-- Footer -->
    <footer>
        <div class="row">
            <div class="col-lg-12">
                <p>Copyright &copy; International Marketing Group 2014</p>
            </div>
        </div>
    </footer>

</div>
<!-- /.container -->
<!-- jQuery Version 1.11.0 -->
<script language="javascript" type="text/javascript" src="<?php echo base_url();?>assets/js/jquery-1.11.1.min.js"></script>
<script language="javascript" type="text/javascript" src="<?php echo base_url();?>assets/js/arbor.js"></script>
<script language="javascript" type="text/javascript" src="<?php echo base_url();?>assets/js/arbor-tween.js"></script>
<script language="javascript" type="text/javascript" src="<?php echo base_url();?>assets/js/main.js"></script>
<script language="javascript" type="text/javascript" src="<?php echo base_url();?>assets/js/system.js"></script>

<script language="javascript" type="text/javascript" src="<?php echo base_url();?>assets/js/graphics.js"></script>
<script language="javascript" type="text/javascript" src="<?php echo base_url();?>assets/js/renderer.js"></script>

<script language="javascript" type="text/javascript" src="<?php echo base_url();?>assets/js/parseur.js"></script>

<!-- Bootstrap Core JavaScript -->
<script  language="javascript" type="text/javascript" src="<?php echo base_url();?>assets/js/bootstrap.min.js"></script>
<script language="javascript" type="text/javascript" src="<?php echo base_url();?>assets/js/halfviz.js"></script>
</body>

</html>
```

Comment: The problem is the js you imported renderer.js is called before the js is loaded, make sure you have correct order of imports.

Comment: before you use rendered, make sure the js is loaded before use

Comment: In future questions, please just post the relevant code: the JS and the `canvas` tag. See [how to ask a good question on Stack Overflow](http://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask).